# Show that $l^1$ is not a closed linear subspace of $l^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Show that $l^1$ is not a closed linear subspace of $l^\infty$.

My task is to pick a specific sequence of sequences from $l^1$ and show that the limit doesn't lie in $l^1$? What else needs to be done?

I would appreciate detailed help as I find the task difficult.

Comment: No, you need to show that a sequence of sequences in $\ell^1$ converges (in $\ell^\infty$ norm) to a sequence in $\ell^\infty \setminus \ell^1$.

Comment: I misspelt, I meant that the limit is not in $l^1$. Is this equivalent to what you suggested? And how do you know the norm in which we are supposed to prove convergence?

Comment: We need to prove the existence of a sequence in $l^1$ that converges in the $l^\infty$-norm to some element of $l^\infty \ \backslash \ l^1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Kenny Wong, my earlier answer was wrong, hence I'm posting the answer suggested by him in the comments of my previous answer.

Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence defined as follows: $$x_n(i)=\begin{cases}\frac1i &\text{ for all } 1 \leq i \leq n\\0 &\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

Then $x_n \in l_1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Let
$x=(1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\cdots)$. Then $ x \in l_{\infty} \setminus l_1$.
Observe:
$$\|x_n-x\|_{\infty}=\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \{\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n+2}\cdots\} \to 0$$
Hence, $$(x_n)\to x \in l_{\infty} \setminus l_1$$

Thus, $l_1$ is not closed in $l_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying fact is that $\operatorname{cl}_{\ell^\infty}\ell^1=c_0$ the subspace of sequences such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$.

I suggest you show that, if $c_{00}$ is the set of eventually null sequences, then $\operatorname{cl}_{\ell^\infty}c_{00}=c_0$. Once you've done that, you conclude with the inclusions $c_{00}\subseteq \ell^1\subseteq c_{0}$.